# How to perform this substitution in sed?

Tags: python, regex, sed

I have this text:

```
Table {\label{seq:ref176}} - Table name.




\begin{longtable}{|m{3.36636in}|m{3.36636in}|}
```

I want to edit it like this:

```
\begin{longtable}{|m{3.36636in}|m{3.36636in}|}
\caption{Table name \label{seq:ref176}}\\
```

I can do this in `Atom` like this:

find: `Table \{\\label\{(.*?)\}\} - (.*?).\n*\\begin\{longtable\}\{(.*?)\|\}`

replace: `\begin{longtable}{$3|}\n\\caption {$2 \\label{$1}}\\\\`

I tried to do this in sed, but it doesn't work. There is no error. Just can't find any matches.

```
s/Table\ \{\\label\{(.*?)\}\}\ \-\ (.*?)\n*\\begin\{longtable\}\{(.*?)\|\}/\\begin\{longtable\}\{\3\|\}\n\\caption\ \{\2\ \\label\{\1\}\}\\\\/g
```

Comment: Please note that sed operates line-by-line; you may want to slurp the entire file with `sed -z`. Your expression gives me an error: `Invalid content of \{\}`.

Comment: @simlev Try `sed -re`

Comment: Ok, with `sed -rz` some substitutions do happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I preferred to write script in `python` rather than `sed`, because it's easier to work with whole file in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import argparse


def test_regex(input):
    with open(input) as f:
        data = f.read()

    file = open("output.tex","w") 
    file.write(data)
    file.close() 

    data = re.sub(r'Table \{\\label\{(.*?)\}\} - (.*?).\s*\\begin\{longtable\}\{(.*?)\|\}',
                  r'\\begin{longtable}{\3|}\n\\caption {\2 \\label{\1}}\\\\', data)

    file = open("output.tex","w") 
    file.write(data)
    file.close() 


def main(input):
    test_regex(input)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("input")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    input = args.input
    main(input)
```

Comment: Makes totally sense: always prefer tools you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

If Perl one-liner is an option, have a try with:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/Table \{(\\label\{.*?\}\}) - (.*?)\.\s+(\\begin\{longtable\}\{.*?\|\})/$3\n\\caption{$2 $1/' file
\begin{longtable}{|m{3.36636in}|m{3.36636in}|}
\caption{Table name \label{seq:ref176}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your try has one conceptual and one minor error.

The concept with `sed` is that it elaborates files line-by-line (by default). Luckily, GNU sed can work on the file as a whole if it is passed the `-z` parameter.

The minor correction is adding a missing `\.` in order to obtain the desired output. I don't blame you because it's really hard to spot such minuscule things when the expression is so long and messy.

**Command line:**

```
sed -rz 's/Table\ \{\\label\{(.*?)\}\}\ \-\ (.*?)\.\n*\\begin\{longtable\}\{(.*?)\|\}/\\begin\{longtable\}\{\3\|\}\n\\caption\ \{\2\ \\label\{\1\}\}\\\\/g' file
```

**Output:**

```
\begin{longtable}{|m{3.36636in}|m{3.36636in}|}
\caption {Table name \label{seq:ref176}}\\
```

**Reference** from the GNU sed [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt)**:**

```
'-z'
'--null-data'
'--zero-terminated'
     Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte
     (the ASCII 'NUL' character) instead of a newline.  This option can
     be used with commands like 'sort -z' and 'find -print0' to process
     arbitrary file names.
```